# Anyway to check whether the page is run in production or dev or test in .net c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know how can I check whether the page is run in production, dev or test in .net c#? in PHP I can use var_dump($_SERVER) to check, but somehow I have no idea how to check it in .net c#.

I need to find out whether the page is run in production/test/dev to display the correct logo and heading on the page

Comment: are you talking about the environment?  like production server, test server and dev server?
code is either build in release or debug mode.

Comment: @c0deNinja: yes.. that's what I mean

Comment: There is no general concept of "prod", "test" or "dev", so there's no general way to find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup as many configuration as you want, by default, you have **Debug** and **Release**.

You can make different **web.config** files for different configuration, for example: web.debug.config

More information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

From code you can use directives to test the configuration, for example:

```
#if DEBUG
  bool isDebug = true;
#else
  bool isDebug = false;
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions could be add build configuration for **Test**, as **Production** could be `Release`, **Dev** could be `Debug`. For test configuration use precomp dirrective like we do for debug.

`TEST` key you have to define in project's **TEST** configuration.

So somewhere on code you will use `#if TEST.`

If you want to use the same build in different environments, can use external configuration file, but I personally would prefer the first solution, as you esplicitly say what build result you want. With config is easy to mess up IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the name of your database server.  This depends on the server naming convention, of course.  So you fetch the ConnectionString out of your web.config, parse out the DataSource and compare it against your known production box.

Another approach is to always sanitize your dev/qa boxes with a certain value in the database that conveys that it's not a production box.

Answer (score 0):

Dont you connect to different database server in every environment? if no server at least the database itself should be different, have a config table with logo url, heading text and other ru.time settings and always build same binaries.

We do this and works very well. only connection string changes in app.config but we seldom redeploy the config file.

Answer (score -3):

System.Environment.MachineName

This will give you the name, so as long as you know the names of the different servers this shoul work.